# how to refresh result count when deleting a row in table using angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have one small label where i am showing total result count of one table data.below i am using one table,On that i'm showing list of data.when i'm deleting one row in table,table is refreshing but in that label result count is not refreshing.Here is my data..

```js
import { VsnApplicationsServiceProxy, VsnApplicationDto , CreateOrEditVsnApplicationDto  } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';
@Component({
  selector: 'vsn-applicationmappings',
  templateUrl: './applicationmappings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./applicationmappings.component.less'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  animations: [appModuleAnimation()]
})
export class ApplicationMappingsComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {
  applications: any;
   constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    private _vsnApplicationsServiceProxy: VsnApplicationsServiceProxy,
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,

  ) {
    super(injector);
  }
ngOnInit() {
 this._vsnApplicationsServiceProxy.getAll("", "", "", "", "", "", "", 0, 100).subscribe((Applications: any) => {
      this.applications = Applications.totalCount;
      
      console.log(' application value', Applications.totalCount);
    });
     }
      getVsnApplications(event?: LazyLoadEvent) {
    if (this.primengTableHelper.shouldResetPaging(event)) {
      this.paginator.changePage(0);
      return;
    }

    this.primengTableHelper.showLoadingIndicator();

    this._vsnApplicationsServiceProxy.getAll(
      this.filterText,
      this.nameFilter,
      this.businessNameFilter,
      this.vsnApplicationTypeNameFilter,
      this.vsnApplicationCategoryNameFilter,
      this.vsnApplicationSubCategoryNameFilter,
      this.primengTableHelper.getSorting(this.dataTable),
      this.primengTableHelper.getSkipCount(this.paginator, event),
      this.primengTableHelper.getMaxResultCount(this.paginator, event)
    ).subscribe(result => {
      this.primengTableHelper.totalRecordsCount = result.totalCount;
      this.primengTableHelper.records = result.items;
      this.primengTableHelper.hideLoadingIndicator();
    });
  }
  reloadPage(): void {
    this.paginator.changePage(this.paginator.getPage());
  }

  createVsnApplication(): void {
     this.createOrEditVsnApplicationModal.show();
  }

  deleteVsnApplication(vsnApplication: VsnApplicationDto): void {
    this.message.confirm(
      '',
      (isConfirmed) => {
        if (isConfirmed) {
          this._vsnApplicationsServiceProxy.delete(vsnApplication.id)
            .subscribe(() => {
              this.reloadPage();
              this.notify.success(this.l('SuccessfullyDeleted'));
            });
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

```html
 <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="box">

                <div><br><br>
                    <h4>{{applications}}</h4>
                </div>
                <div> <span>
                        <h6>Applications</h6> 
                    </span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-content">
    <div class="m-portlet m-portlet--mobile">
        <div class="m-portlet__body">
            <div class="primeng-datatable-container" [busyIf]="primengTableHelper.isLoading">
                <p-table #dataTable (onLazyLoad)="getVsnApplications($event)" [value]="primengTableHelper.records"
                    rows="{{primengTableHelper.defaultRecordsCountPerPage}}" [paginator]="false" [lazy]="true"
                    [scrollable]="true" ScrollWidth="100%" [responsive]="primengTableHelper.isResponsive"
                    [resizableColumns]="primengTableHelper.resizableColumns">
                    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 150px" pSortableColumn="vsnApplicationType.name">
                                {{l("ApplicationName")}}
                                <p-sortIcon field="vsnApplication.name"></p-sortIcon>
                            </th>
                             <th style="width: 130px"
                                [hidden]="!isGrantedAny('Pages.Administration.VsnApplicationTypes.Edit', 'Pages.Administration.VsnApplicationTypes.Delete')">
                                {{l('Actions')}}</th>

                        </tr>
                        </ng-template>
                          <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-record="$implicit">
                        <tr>

                            <td style="width:150px">
                                <span class="ui-column-title"> {{l("ApplicationName")}}</span>
                                 {{record.vsnApplication.businessName}}
                            </td>
                              <td style="width: 130px"
                                [hidden]="!isGrantedAny('Pages.Administration.VsnApplications.Edit', 'Pages.Administration.VsnApplications.Delete')">
                                <div class="btn-group dropdown" dropdown container="body">
                                    <button class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-sm btn-primary" dropdownToggle>
                                        <i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span class="caret"></span> {{l("Actions")}}
                                    </button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" *dropdownMenu>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="javascript:;"
                                                (click)="viewVsnApplicationModal.show(record)">{{l('View')}}</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="javascript:;"
                                                *ngIf="permission.isGranted('Pages.Administration.VsnApplicationTypes.Edit')"
                                                (click)="createOrEditVsnApplicationModal.show(record.vsnApplication.id)">{{l('Edit')}}</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="javascript:;"
                                                *ngIf="permission.isGranted('Pages.Administration.VsnApplicationTypes.Delete')"
                                                (click)="deleteVsnApplication(record.vsnApplication)">{{l('Delete')}}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                </p-table>
                  <div class="primeng-no-data" *ngIf="primengTableHelper.totalRecordsCount == 0">
                    {{l('NoData')}}
                </div>
                <div class="primeng-paging-container">
                    <p-paginator rows="{{primengTableHelper.defaultRecordsCountPerPage}}" #paginator
                        (onPageChange)="getVsnApplications($event)"
                        [totalRecords]="primengTableHelper.totalRecordsCount"
                        [rowsPerPageOptions]="primengTableHelper.predefinedRecordsCountPerPage">
                    </p-paginator>
                    <span class="total-records-count">
                        {{l('TotalRecordsCount', primengTableHelper.totalRecordsCount)}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <createOrEditVsnApplicationModal #createOrEditVsnApplicationModal (modalSave)="getVsnApplications()">
        </createOrEditVsnApplicationModal>
        <viewVsnApplicationModal #viewVsnApplicationModal></viewVsnApplicationModal>
</div>
```

When deleting one row, the table is refreshing and showing updated records.but in that result count lable is not refreshing.I searched in stack overflow,I found that we have to give like splice(id,1)
but it is not working,any suggestions would great help..

Comment: You want to update `this.primengTableHelper.records` these count?

Comment: No sir,In ngOnInit() method i declared a variable called this.applications where  i am getting total count using vsnApplicationServiceProxy.getAll().I want to update this variable only.

Comment: can you create https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w6dxqp